# subtractByKey modifes values in the source RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm experiencing a problem with `subtractByKey` using Spark 2.0.2 with Scala 2.11.x (it also reproduces with Spark 1.6.2 and Scala 2.10):

Relevant code:

```
object Types {
   type ContentId = Int
   type ContentKey = Tuple2[Int, ContentId]
   type InternalContentId = Int
}

val inverseItemIDMap: RDD[(InternalContentId, ContentKey)] = itemIDMap.map(_.swap).cache()
logger.info(s"Built an inverse map of ${inverseItemIDMap.count()} item IDs")
logger.info(inverseItemIDMap.collect().mkString("I->E ", "\nI->E ", ""))

val superfluousItems: RDD[(InternalContentId, Int)] = .. .cache()
logger.info(superfluousItems.collect().mkString("SI ", "\nSI ", ""))

val filteredInverseItemIDMap: RDD[(InternalContentId, ContentKey)] = 
  inverseItemIDMap.subtractByKey(superfluousItems).cache() // <<===!!!
logger.info(s"${filteredInverseItemIDMap.count()} items in the filtered inverse ID mapping")
logger.info(filteredInverseItemIDMap.collect().mkString("F I->E ", "\nF I->E ", ""))
```

The operation in question is `.subtractByKey`. Both RDDs involved are cached and forced via `count()` prior to calling `subtractByKey`, so I would expect the result to be unaffected by how exactly `superfluousItems` is built.

I added debugging output and filtered the resulting logs by relevant `InternalContentId` values (829911, 830071). Output:

```
Built an inverse map of 827354 item IDs
.
.
I->E (829911,(2,1135081))
I->E (830071,(1,2295102))
.
.
748190 items in the training set had less than 28 ratings
SI (829911,3)
.
.
79164 items in the filtered inverse ID mapping
F I->E (830071,(2,1135081))
```

There's no element with key 830071 in superfluousItems (SI), so it's not removed from the source RDD. However, its value is for some reason replaced with the one from key 829911. How could this be? I cannot reproduce it locally - only when running on a multi-machine cluster. Is this a bug or I'm missing something?

Comment: Are the types here, like `type InternalContentId = Int` the actual types used in the code? From looking at the code (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/SubtractedRDD.scala#L122), I don't see how this could happen, unless the hashkey for the key is somehow buggy (Which cannot be the case for `Int`)

Comment: Yes, key types are exactly the same. I tried replacing type aliases with `Int` with no luck as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I assumed that caching and forcing an RDD guarantees that it will never be re-evaluated. `inverseItemIDMap` is built using a non-deterministic operation, and multiple uses of it also give different results:

```
val itemIDMap: RDD[(ContentKey, InternalContentId)] =
  rawEvents
  .map(_.content)
  .distinct
  .zipWithUniqueId()
  .map(u => (u._1, u._2.toInt))
  .cache()
logger.info(s"Built a map of ${itemIDMap.count()} item IDs")
val inverseItemIDMap: RDD[(InternalContentId, ContentKey)] =
  itemIDMap.map(_.swap).cache()
```

I made the operation stable by adding `.sortBy(c => c)` before `.zipWithUniqueId()` and this solved the issue.